# Looking for an "irreducible equivalence predicate" on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, numerical-methods

**NB:** although I find it easier to couch the question below in somewhat abstract mathematical terms, I am ultimately interested in functions and data types that I can easily and efficiently implement in a general-purpose programming language like C, Python, Scheme, or Haskell.

---

By an "*equivalence predicate* on $X$" all I mean is a Boolean-valued function $P$ on $X \times X$ that *induces* an equivalence<sup>1</sup> on $X$.

It often happens that such a predicate can be readily reduced to an application of a canonical equality predicate ($(r, s) \mapsto$ "$r$ is equal to $s$") to the results of some suitable "classifier" function with domain $X$.

For example, the equivalence predicate $G_5$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ that assigns to $(m, n) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ the truth-value of the proposition "$m - n$ is divisible by $5$" can be readily reduced to applying the appropriate canonical equality predicate to $g_5(m)$ and $g_5(n)$, where $g_5$ is the classifier given by $k \mapsto \mathrm{mod}(k, 5)$.  Symbolically:

$$G_5 = \mathbf{Eq}_\mathbf{5} \circ (g_5 \times g_5).$$

Such a factoring of an equivalence predicate is computationally attractive because, when compared to binary equivalence predicates, their factor unary classifiers are easier to tabulate (so they can be more easily pre-computed or memoized).  This means that the computation of the equivalence predicate can be replaced by a couple of array look-ups and a simple equality test.

I am looking for an example of an equivalence predicate that do ***not*** lend themselves to this strategy because any factoring classifier for them would be very difficult, or impossible, to implement efficiently.  IOW, for such predicates, it is easier to compute the predicate directly.

My preference would be for a predicate on $\mathbb{Z}$, but one on $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, or on some IEEE 754 floating point type would be OK too.

EDIT: I should have mentioned also that I'm interested in a predicate that induces a not-too-trivial equivalence on its domain.    To a first approximation, a "nice" equivalence is one where the number of classes is greater than 1, but much smaller than the size of the underlying set, and where the cardinalities of all the individual classes are roughly equal.  The equivalence induced by predicate $G_5$ of the example above is emblematic of an "ideal" equivalence.

In the next section I attempt to formalize some of the fuzzier bits in the description above.  *It's a slog to read*.  If the above description is good enough for you, don't bother reading the rest of this post.

---

**NB:** In what follows, $\mathit{t}$ and $\mathit{f}$ stand for "true" and "false", respectively.  Also, I'll use "$P(x, y)$ holds" to mean that $P(x, y) = \mathit{t}$.  Also, for this post I had no choice but to coin a lot of terminology, something I hate to do.  Please, don't hesitate to point out more widely accepted terminology.

To recap, an *equivalence predicate* on $X$ is a function $P: X \times X \to \{\mathit{t}, \mathit{f}\}$, such that the set of pairs $(x, y)$ for which $P(x, y)$ holds constitute an equivalence $X$.

For every set $X$, a simple example of an equivalence predicate is the previously-mentioned canonical equality predicate $\mathbf{Eq}_X$, which holds if and only if its two arguments are identical; it induces the trivial equivalence whose classes are the singletons of $X$.

For a non-trivial example, let $X = \mathbb{Z}$, and let $G_5$ be the predicate on $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ that holds if and only if $x - y$ is divisible by $5$.

A suitable equivalence predicate is one way to specify an equivalence on $X$.  Another way is through a suitable *classifier* function $g$ on $X$.  In this approach, the induced equivalence consists of the inverse images $g^{-1}(\{y\})$ of singletons $y \in \mathrm{im}(g)$.

For example, the classifier $g_5:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbf{5} := \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}, z \mapsto \mathrm{mod}(z, 5)$ induces the same equivalence on $\mathbb{Z}$ as does the equivalence predicate $G_5$ from the previous example.

It's not hard to see that the binary predicate $G_5$ can be expressed in terms of the unary classifier $g_5$:

$$G_5 = \mathbf{Eq}_\mathbf{5} \circ (g_5 \times g_5).$$

...where $(g_5 \times g_5)$ denotes the function $(x, y) \mapsto (g_5(x), g_5(y))$.

Let $P$ be an equivalence predicate on $X$, and let $\mathscr{G}$ be a set of functions on $X$.  I'll say that $P$ is *reducible* in $\mathscr{G}$ iff $\exists p \in \mathscr{G}$ such that

$$P = \mathbf{Eq}_{\mathrm{cod}(p)} \circ (p \times p).$$

Otherwise, I'll say that $P$ is *irreducible* in $\mathscr{G}$.

Of course, the richer $\mathscr{G}$ is, the more interesting the irreducibility in $\mathscr{G}$ of some predicate $P$ becomes.

I'm looking for an example of an equivalence predicate that is irreducible in an "interestingly large" set of functions $\mathscr{G}$.  For example $\mathscr{G}$ could be something in the spirit of "functions $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ that can be easily and efficiently implemented in a general-purpose computer programming language."  Yes, this is super-vague, but one could view the problem of making this statement more precise as part of the question.

---

<sup>1</sup> This means that $P:X \times X \to \{\mathit{t}, \mathit{f}\}$ is such that, for all $x, y, z \in X$,

1. $P(x, x)$ holds (reflexivity);
2. $P(x, y) \Rightarrow P(y, x)$ (symmetry);
3. $P(x, y) \wedge P(y, z) \Rightarrow P(x, z)$ (transitivity).

Comment: Extreme example: Let $T$ be a Turing machine. Let $a$ be equivalent to $b$ if $T$ halts on inputs $a$ and $b$ or does not halt on inputs $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I knew that choosing the [computability] tag for this question was a bad idea...

Comment: What is not clear to me is that you are asking both for an equivalence class _and_ a set of functions $\mathcal G$, but with your own example, you could take any $\mathcal G$ and the set $\mathcal G':=\mathcal G-\{\mod(\cdot,5)\}$ would satisfy your requirements. Also your original tags were much closer to your question than the current ones.

Comment: @yoyo311: I plead guilty on all counts.  Indeed my attempt to sharpen/formalize the informal description (of the post's first part) is pretty hopeless.  I probably should get rid of it altogether...  Maybe I should phrase it like this: I'm looking for a binary predicate that is "easy to compute" (as in the product of two large primes is "easy to compute"), and for which any known factoring classifier is "hard to compute" (as in factors of the product of two large primes are "hard to compute").

Comment: I applaud your attempt to formalize your question, I am fairly sure that finding out the restrictions on $\mathcal G$ exactly will lead you straight to an answer. However, if I understand your question correctly then I do not think this is possible because every equivalence relation can be factored uniquely, and since the factored term is "hard to compute" (ie nonpolynomial), then the relation itself will be hard to compute. (please correct me if I am wrong).